# Scheme- Memoization with "force" and "delay" speed comparison

Tags: scheme, lazy-evaluation, fibonacci, memoization

```
(define fibo   ; fibonacci
  (lambda (n)
    (cond ((= n 0) 0)
          ((= n 1) 1)
          ((= n 2) 1)
          (else (+ (fibo (- n 1)) (fibo(- n 2))
     )))))

(time (fibo 20))

(define (fiboN n)   ; fibonacci
    (delay (cond ((= n 0) 0)
          ((= n 1) 1)
          ((= n 2) 1)
          (else (+ (force (fiboN (- n 1))) (force (fiboN(- n 2))))))))

(time force( force (fiboN 20)))
```

Given the two fibonacci functions above, I expected that the second would run faster since scheme applies memoization on forced delayed objects.

Yet the second fiboN runs slower. Why would that be? Am I wrong about automatic memoization in Scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confounding memoization with delayed (a.k.a. *lazy*) evaluation - take a look at this [explanation](http://community.schemewiki.org/?memoization) to understand the difference between the two concepts.

Your second implementation of `fiboN` is delayed, of course, but it's not memoizing anything - sure, once we `force` a value it won't have to be forced again, but it doesn't change the fact that this is a recursive function that gets called over and over again for values that we already obtained, and the extra cost of delaying/forcing each value will make it slower than the first implementation.

Here's a possible implementation that *really* uses memoization, the trick is to save already-calculated values somewhere where we can access them efficiently - a hash table in this example:

```
(define fiboN
  (let ((memo (make-hash '((0 . 0) (1 . 1)))))
    (lambda (n)
      (unless (hash-has-key? memo n)
        (hash-set! memo n (+ (fiboN (- n 1)) (fiboN (- n 2)))))
      (hash-ref memo n))))
```

And the results show that this is much faster:

```
(time (fiboN 100))

cpu time: 0 real time: 1 gc time: 0
354224848179261915075
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand how the values in your version are memoized. However, are the values in the first version of fibo stored at all as in the second version? If not, then is it true then the cost of delay and force in terms of speed is more than the saving of any stored values?